# display values on dropdown from database and store the selected value back to database in a different table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a project where I want to display a dropdown list from database which I am able to do but I am stuck on the part after selection is made and I am not getting the selected value in database.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="close">+</div>
    <h2> Select preferred advisor from dropdown</h2>
<?php
    $query="SELECT advisor_name FROM advisor_names";
    $queryenter code here_run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
    {
        echo '<select name="Advisors">';
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
        {
            $selected_advisor=$rows['advisor_name'];
            echo "<option value>".$row["advisor_name"]."</option>";
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
    ?>
  <br><br>

  <a href=""> <input name="mod_btn" type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"></a>
<!--  <a href=""> <input name="mod_btn" type="submit" class="button"></a> -->
  <!--<input type="submit">-->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mod_btn']))
{
    $query="INSERT INTO `appointment`(`number`, `advisor`) VALUES (NULL,'$selected_advisor');";
    $query_run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if($query_run)
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Query run sucessful")</script>';
    }
}
```

The query executes but the value is not shown in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't populate a value for each option and by specifying `value` in the option tag you're making the value blank:

```
echo "<option value>".$row["advisor_name"]."</option>";
```

What you should do is this:

```
echo "<option value=".$row["advisor_name"].">".$row["advisor_name"]."</option>";
```

Additionally, you would not use `$selected_insert` in the query unless you have munged the variable. Instead, you should probably use `$_POST['Advisors']`.

Then, to top it all of you should get in the habit of using prepared statements for all of your queries. If not, you're leaving yourself wide open to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Might be worth, although it leads down the old rabbit hole, mentioning that `$selected_advisor` will not be what you would use in the INSERT query

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly - I was cramming lunch down my throat while typing with one hand :)

Comment: I will have that image in my head all evening now :)

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestion.